# Дружественные числа.Как оптимизация перебор?(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sumNumDivs(num):
divs_sum = -num
div = 1
while div * div <= num:
    if num % div == 0:
        if div == num // div:
            divs_sum += div
        else:
            divs_sum += div
            divs_sum += num // div
    div += 1
return divs_sum

first, last = map(int, input().split())
c = 0
for z in range(first, last + 1):
    for k in range(z+1, last + 1):
        if sumNumDivs(z) == k and sumNumDivs(k) == z:
            print("(", z, ',', k, ")", sep='', end=' ')
            c += 1
if c < 1:
    print(0)
```

Как сократить время работы?Я так понимаю проблема в переборе и сравнении.

Comment: У вас получилась dn - сумма делителей для числа n. Ей может соответствовать только одно число m=dn. Проверьте сумму делителей m. Внутренний цикл не нужен.

Comment: Допилил цикл по этому совету,время работы сократилось в разы. Думаю после мемоизации код будет работать еще быстрее.

Comment: Не забывайте проверять, чтобы сумма попала в интервал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы добавите счетчик к вызовам функции sumNumDivs, то увидите, что она вызывается очень много раз для тех же самых чисел. А это явный признак сделать "мемоизацию". Есть много техник, но в данном случае хорошо так, после функции sumNumDivs добавляем такое:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:            
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper

sumNumDivs = memoize(sumNumDivs)
```

запускаем и наслаждаемся.

По факту, можно вначале просто пройтись по числам и сделать массив кол-ва делителей. А потом уже по нему смотреть. Это может оказаться сильно быстрее.